# Python - Trying to create a simple antispam filter

Tags: python, input, spam

I have to program a simple spam filter for my thesis for my graduation. My purpose is to open and read a two different lists, one for spam and one for ham. The name (cartella) is like folder in English. The problem is that when I print spam, it prints only the first element of array `spam[0]` and when I print the length it prints 1, but it should print 1500. The problem is in the function. I need help.

This is my code:

```
import nltk 
import os

def importalista(cartella):
    lista=[]
    listafile=os.listdir(cartella)
    for file in listafile:
        f=open(cartella + file, 'r+')
        lista.append(f.read())
        f.close()

        return lista

spam = importalista('C:\\enron1\\spam\\')
ham = importalista('C:\\enron1\\ham\\')
print(len(spam))
```

Comment: Since the `return` statement is inside your `for` loop, your loop will only ever run for one iteration. If you move the `return` out of the `for` loop, it will return after the `for` loop has completed.

Comment: Your return statement shouldn't be indented, right? Now you're returning after reading the first file.

Comment: Thank for your reply.. So where should i put the return line?

Answer (score 0):

You have return statement inside the for loop. It will exit the function after the first iteration. if you change your code as follows, it would be correct. 
    import nltk 
    import os

```
def importalista(cartella):
    lista=[]
    listafile=os.listdir(cartella)
    for file in listafile:
        f=open(cartella + file, 'r+')
        lista.append(f.read())
        f.close()

    return lista

spam = importalista('C:\\enron1\\spam\\')
ham = importalista('C:\\enron1\\ham\\')
print(len(spam))
```

Comment: Thank for your reply.. So where should i put the return line?

Comment: Thank for your reply.. So where should i put the return line?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1651: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: It's because your filter file has some characters that can't be encoded with default settings. When you open a file, please use open(filename, encoding='utf8') to avoid such encoding errors.